# Are all $v \in N(A - \lambda I)$ eigenvectors or are just some $v \in N(A - \lambda I)$ eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let's say I have an arbitrary matrix $A$.

An eigenvector of $A$ would be a vector $\vec{x}$, such that

1. $A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}$
2. $\vec{x} \in N(A-\lambda I)$ i.e. $(A - \lambda I)\vec{x} = \vec{0}$

where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\vec{x}$

---

Now are all $\vec{x} \in N(A-\lambda I)$ eigenvectors of $A$, i.e. do all $\vec{x}$ in the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$ also automatically satisfy condition $(1)$, that $A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}$?

Written more concretely is the following statement true:

$$\vec{x} \in N(A-\lambda I) \implies A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x} \ \ \ \ \ \forall   \vec{x} \in N(A-\lambda I)$$

If that was the case then the eigenvectors, would $span$ the entire nullspace.

Furthemore what relation does $N(A-\lambda I)$ have to $N(A)$ and the eigenvectors? If $\vec{x} \in N(A-\lambda I)$, does that imply that $\vec{x} \in N(A)$? Can we deduce anything about the eigenvectors of $A$ from $N(A)$ or can we only deduce them from $N(A - \lambda I)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your title question is "just some", because there is a single exception: the null vector.

By definition, an eigenvalue of $A$ relative to $\lambda$ is a *nonzero* vector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$ (forgive me if I don't use arrows for vectors). Now
$$
Ax=\lambda x
\iff
Ax-(\lambda I)x=0
\iff
(A-\lambda I)x=0
\iff
x\in N(A-\lambda I)
$$
so the only exception is the vector that is not an eigenvector by definition, that is the zero vector.

Of course, if your definition allows $0$ to be an eigenvector, then the answer to the title question is "all". However, most books on the subjects don't consider $0$ an eigenvector, so check carefully yours.

---

About relationships between the eigenvalues/eigenvectors and $N(A)$, I'm afraid there's none: consider simply the case of an invertible matrix, which can have any set of nonzero eigenvalues compatible with its order, but has $N(A)=0$.

Comment: @Bye_World I'm not sure how it's possible to call $0$ an eigenvector without having to do several distinctions that make the thing complicated. I carefully distinguish between *eigenvectors* (nonzero) and the *eigenspace*, that is, $N(A-\lambda I)$, whose dimension is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

I'll to answer one question at a time.
First of all, your claims 1 and 2 are the same.
if $Ax =\lambda x$, then note that $Ax = \lambda I x$ and thus we can factor out the $x$ on both sides and then subtract the RHS from the LHS, getting $(A - \lambda I)x =0.$ This means that $x \in N(A - \lambda I).$
In other words, the claims $x \in N(A - \lambda I)$ and $Ax =\lambda x$ are equivalent.

By inspecting the equation $(A - \lambda I)x =0,$ evidently $\alpha x$ also works for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus you are correct in saying that any vector in $N(A - \lambda I)$ is also an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda.$
In other words, any vector in the subspace $N(A - \lambda I)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda.$
So you could say that $(\lambda, N(A - \lambda I))$ is an eigenvalue-eigensubspace pair for $A$, but nobody does.
Typically we use normalized eigenvectors, i.e., we use the eigenvector such that $||x||=1.$
This narrows it down to $\alpha = \pm 1,$
so there's still a bit of abiguity there.

When you say that the eigenvectors span the nullspace, you are sort of correct. Be more precise: "any eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$ spans the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$"

Last paragraph of the question: any eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue of 0 does lie in the null space of $A$ (why?).
You might remember reading somewhere that the rank of a matrix is related to the dimension of its null space and the number of eigenvalues equal to zero.  I'll let you draw the rest of the connection here.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is correct by the definition of nullspace, as $x\in N(A-\lambda I)$, then all those vectors should fulfill the relationship $(A-\lambda I)x=0$, from where we can derive easily the relation $Ax=\lambda x$.

For the statement you make that if $x\in N(a-\lambda I)$ then $x\in N(A)$, it is false as it can be seen in the next counterexample. Consider matrix A:
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right)$, it can be clearly seen that the nullspace of this matrix is zero dimensional. However, it has eigenvectors $a=(1,0),b=(0,1)$, which form the nullspace of the matrix $A-\lambda I$, that is the zero matrix, so being in that nullspace does not imply to be in the nullspace of $A$